# How can I obtain a list of page posts including ghost/dark posts for a page?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

The regular `https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/posts?access_token___` call just returns standard page posts. How can I include these?

Comment: Are you talking about the posts that are greyed out due to being flagged by the spam filter?

Answer (score 8):

From the [blog post which announced this feature](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/07/23/new-marketing-tools-for-pages/):

> You might ask how you would read a list of all scheduled and
>   unpublished page post through API. Graph API's Page object provides a
>   new connection, `promotable_posts`, that lists all `published`,
>   `scheduled`, and `unpublished` Page posts. Also, you can use [FQL
>   stream
>   table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) for
>   this purpose as described
>   [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page).

(under the header **Unpublished / Scheduled Page Posts**)

So `https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/promotable_posts?access_token___` is how to access the posts.

Comment: lgy you saved my job! <3<3<3